# What is name of this plugin or SQL?

Tags: jquery, sql, plugins

In following link after revolution slider and in post location and other locations; it's seems to be a plugin that can show the posts or portfolio in slide style with button and lower; gallery with this plugin

http://happykidswp.creaws.com

[image]

Is this a plugin?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) Questions that rely **purely** on off-site information are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, because external links rot, making the question useless to others in the future (the primary goal of SO), and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be using [`OwlCarousel`](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) as per the picture:

[image]